# change css when scrolling at certain element

Tags: css, colors, scroll, window

I have this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  $("h1").css("color", "white");
});
```

Now my problem: I don't want it to change the css immediately when you begin scrolling. So where can I state when this function should happen?

More specific: I want it to do this at a certain div, is that possible?

Here is a example of what I got: http://jsfiddle.net/k5ugL/
When you scroll down and arrive at the black div, the title should turn white, how do I do that?

Comment: Would recommend creating an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/) to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: change `$(window)` to your div class or ID `$(".divClass")` and when ever you scroll the mouse wheel on that div the `h1` should change color

Answer (score 0):

This js will be executed when you scroll 50 pixels from top of window. Does this answer your question?

```
$(window).scroll( function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) $("h1").addClass("myclass");
    else $("h1").removeClass("myclass");    
});
```

Better to use classes than inline styles where possible.